# Salesforce mobile SDK sync when user comes from offline mode to Online

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

In our mobile app we are using Salesforce mobile SDK. Everything works fine for data synchronisation on online mode. But there is one issue offline with Android which I am not able to overcome. Please see if you can give me some hints to resolve this problem.

In this app managed four objects:-

1. Application
2. Assessment Checklist
3. Checklist Assessment Question
4. Assessment Checklist Section

The app performs perfectly in synchronising data with Salesforce in online mode. but encounters a challenge in offline mode. When offline, the app stores data locally and upon reconnecting online, it synchronises the stored data. However, the issue lies in the synchronisation sequence. Specifically, the Assessment Checklist Record data synchronises before the Assessment Checklist Question data.

The assessment checklist questions must be fully synchronised first, before the assessment checklist record is synced and completed on Salesforce, because Salesforce uses the questions to create a assessment report.which must exist before Salesforce generates the assessment report PDF. and this report pdf create after the assessment Checklist record update.

Synchronization sequence in the below image:-

[image]

But the assessment Checklist record  synced before the assessment question.

Consequently, this leads to complications in generating the Assessment Report as changes related to Assessment Checklist Questions aren't synchronised adequately before the Report creation.

Could you please suggest a solution to this issue?